# How to store Json Array In ArrayList

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, arraylist

> I am getting data from json.In my json there are 2 array.

1. Main Array
2. Under main array there is several object and Under that object i am getting one another array.

**The Problem is, when First Object read then its goes to  ParseLiveComment (GET CALL see Below code ) and read all object then return all comment and display in List**

**But i want , when First Object read then its goes to  ParseLiveComment (GET CALL see Below code ) and then add first object comment Data and add to comment arraylist , and so on**

**This is my Json**

```
    {
    "status": 1,
    "product": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "product_name_en": "testProduct",
            "product_name_ar": "testProduct",
            "product_description_en": "This is test product",
            "product_description_ar": "This is test product",
            "link": [
                "http://kartpay.biz/api/v1/file/product/WMZv45E8UCWhIG95ammJSF9GePbz6CjgfskkRPK9.jpg"
            ],
            "starting_price": "1000.000",
            "sub_category_id": "1",
            "status": "A",
            "user_id": "1",
            "view_count": null,
            "like_count": null,
            "comment_count": 1,
            "comment": [
                {
                    "product_id": "1",
                    "user_id": "1",
                    "comment": "Good and nice product"
                }
            ],
            "first_name_en": null,
            "first_name_ar": null,
            "last_name_en": null,
            "last_name_ar": null,
            "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 8:11 AM",
            "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 8:11 AM"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "product_name_en": "testProducts",
            "product_name_ar": "testProducts",
            "product_description_en": "This is test products",
            "product_description_ar": "This is test",
            "link": [
                "http://kartpay.biz/api/v1/file/product/FjtsAmhCxINBhleAl2sTtKcZehHokRaoO1T2aYW4.jpg",
                "http://kartpay.biz/api/v1/file/product/LNG9gTlvnHzOpi3Hb5WNoWR8YN1oXuHwOOA6Nbqn.jpg"
            ],
            "starting_price": "1000.000",
            "sub_category_id": "1",
            "status": "A",
            "user_id": "1",
            "view_count": null,
            "like_count": null,
            "comment_count": 0,
            "comment": [],
            "first_name_en": null,
            "first_name_ar": null,
            "last_name_en": null,
            "last_name_ar": null,
            "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 8:19 AM",
            "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 8:19 AM"
        }
]
}
```

**I am successfully get main Array in Array List  But I want to Store that comment Array in Another Array list  as per**

**This is my Pojo classes for both arraylist**

```
 public class CardData implements ECCardData<Comment> {

   private List<Comment> listItems;
 @Override
    public List<Comment> getListItems() {
        return listItems;
    }

    public void setListItems(List<Comment> listItems) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }
}
```

> Comment POJO

```
 public class Comment {

    private String commentText;
    public String getCommentText() {
        return commentText;
    }

    public void setCommentText(String commentText) {
        this.commentText = commentText;
    }
}
```

**This is my Parsing**

```
 public static ArrayList<CardData> PaeseLiveProducts(String response) throws JSONException {
ArrayList<CardData> alUser = new ArrayList<>();

  JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(response);

    JSONArray parentArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("product");
    for (int j = 0; j < parentArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(j);
        CardData user = new CardData();

     int  is=   user.setId(finalObject.getInt("id"));

        Comment comment = new Comment();

        JSONArray jsonArray=finalObject.getJSONArray("link");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            // Log.d("text", textArray.getString(i) );
            user.setHeadBackgroundResource(jsonArray.getString(i));
        }

        JSONArray jsonArray1 = finalObject.getJSONArray("comment");
        for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray1.length(); k++) {
            // Log.d("text", textArray.getString(i) );
            JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(k);
            comment.setCommentText(jsonObject2.getString("comment"));
        }

        user.setListItems(PaeseLive(response));


        alUser.add(user);


    }
    return alUser;
}

public static ArrayList<Comment> PaeseLiveComment(String response) throws JSONException {

    ArrayList<Comment> alUser = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray parentArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("product");

    for (int j = 0; j < parentArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(j);
        Comment comment = new Comment();

        JSONArray jsonArray1 = finalObject.getJSONArray("comment");
        for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray1.length(); k++) {
            // Log.d("text", textArray.getString(i) );
            JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(k);
            comment.setCommentText(jsonObject2.getString("comment"));
        }
         alUser.add(comment);

    }
    return alUser;
    // return alUser;
}
```

[image: Here in All comment List Display at a time , i want to show onlyfor particular product_id]

Comment: Did you try `GSON` ? I think Gson will be convenient than manual parsing.

Comment: Parsing is  working perfectly but problem is  when it read first object then it read all comment array. I want when it read first main object then it read that object comment array , when it second , then read 2nd object comment array and so on

Comment: your description is quite confusing, Can you explain when you get the first item then what do you want exactly. As far as I understand you want to take the array of comments and parse it ?

Comment: yes exactly right. but it should add in comment Arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code? :

```
public static ArrayList<Comment> PaeseLiveComment(String response) throws JSONException {

    ArrayList<Comment> alUser = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray parentArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("product");

    for (int j = 0; j < parentArray.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(j);

        JSONArray jsonArray1 = finalObject.getJSONArray("comment");
        for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray1.length(); k++) {
            // Log.d("text", textArray.getString(i) );
            Comment comment = new Comment();
            JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(k);
            comment.setCommentText(jsonObject2.getString("comment"));
            alUser.add(comment);
        }

    }
    return alUser;
    // return alUser;
}
```